# Eclipse Window->Show View all entries are grayed out

Tags: eclipse

After the lastest update from eclipse (Helios Service Release 2) in the menu `Window->Show View` all entries are grayed out now. If I close a view, there no change to display it again (except resetting the perspective). What can be the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: Not sure of the reason, but perhaps try the "-clean" option when starting.

Comment: The -clean option did not help, res-installing eclipse solved the problem.